# I am trying to get the menu of Android working and

Tags: android, android-menu

### Main Activity

```
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)
{
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menumenu, menu);
    return true;
}

public void myClickHandler(View v) 
{ 
    switch(v.getId()) 
    { 
         case R.id.resetscoreboard:
             scoreboardreset();
             topText.setText("Scoreboard Has Been Reset!!");

    }
}
```

### menumenu.xml

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/resetscoreboard"
    android:title="Reset Scoreboard"
    android:orderInCategory="1"
    android:onClick="myClickHandler">

</item>
```

Could you tell me why it does not do anything when I pull up the menu and click on it?

Thanks a lot, experts @ stack overflow!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of defining click Handler, you need to implement:

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch(item.getItemId()) {

    case R.id.resetscoreboard:
       scoreboardreset();
       topText.setText("Scoreboard Has Been Reset!!");
       break;

    default:
        break;
    }

    return true;
}
```

Go through [this](http://www.barebonescoder.com/2010/07/android-development-simple-menu-handling/) example to get exact idea for the implementation of Menu in Android.

Comment: @user979431 but you can give only ^1 :)

Answer (score 0):

You should not use `android:onClick` attribute here.

Instead, override the method `onOptionsItemSelected`.